# How do I set a JavaScript variable with info from an HTML textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I set a JavaScript variable with a string value that I get from an HTML text form?

I am absolutely new to HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

```
var textvalue = document.getElementById("insertidoftextarea").value;
```

should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<textarea id="foo">Hello</textarea>
```

JS:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
alert(foo.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of what you asked:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test Input</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function testResults (form) {
    var TestVar = form.inputbox.value;
    alert ("You typed: " + TestVar);
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Enter something in the box: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE=""><P>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```